# TextBox DateTime format

Tags: c#, datetime, textbox

Im wondering how to make my textbox format "DD.MM.YYYY" that after load form the textbox will be filled with "__ .__ .*_*_" and those spaces and dots cannot be deleted. Is there any way to do that? 
Thanks

Comment: Its called a MaskedTextBox... If you googled ` textbox format "DD.MM.YYYY" ` you would have easily found it...

Comment: Is this Winforms? What's wrong with `DateTimePicker`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why don't you use a [MaskedTextbox](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.maskedtextbox.aspx)? Use the following as mask, you can set the mask either at design time or at form load.

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   maskedTextBox1.Mask = "00.00.0000";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You would probably be looking at something like [Ajax Masked Edit](http://www.asp.net/ajaxLibrary/AjaxControlToolkitSampleSite/MaskedEdit/MaskedEdit.aspx)

Another way to do it would be to use a [jquery plugin](http://digitalbush.com/projects/masked-input-plugin/)

Answer (score 0):

You could use a MaskedTextbox that will do exactly what you describe. A DateTimePicker might be better though...